# Send android push notification to all except one user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase and I have an application where I need to send notification to all users. So to achieve that I have created a topic allUsers to which every device subscribes. Now if I send push notification to this topic, every device received it. I want to exclude one device, which is indirectly creating push notification to /topics/allUsers.

Is this achievable.?

Answer (score 5):

Update:

For Android, what I do is, I include a sender custom value in the payload, check if the value is the same as the current user's id, if it is, I don't show the notification.

---

Topics Messaging works simply that **all** subscribers would receive the message sent to the corresponding topic.

You can't exclude a specific subscriber. You're going to have to:

- create a separate topic where the user won't be subscribed
- unsubscribe the user to the corresponding topic
- or send the message to the specific users only using `registration_ids` instead

Other than that, there is currently no other workaround on what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Might be a little late, but after reading [Frank´s post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html), I came with the idea to create your topic for all users and then a topic for each user, then when sending a message, you can add topic conditions such as:

```
('AllUsers' in topics) && !('user_foo' in topics)
```

Comment: creating a separate topic for each user is not a good idea. According to Firebase documentation there is the limit of 2000 topics your application can have.

Comment: actually, the 2000 topics limit is on the client app, which means that a user can't subscribe to more than 2000 topics (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)

Comment: You don't need to create 2000+ topics. Simply create one main topic that all users subscribe to then one unique topic (like a user ID) that each individual user subscribes to.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can do this.** Go to your Firebase console, click on your project panel and there navigate to Grow/Notifications tab. There you can send messages (push notifications) to your app users and adjust everything related to the message and targeting there:

[image]

Comment: how to do this programmatically from the server. I have spring based server.